# R pROC precision

Tags: r, precision, proc

I want to use the pROC package and find the precision. The problem is I DO NOT have the TP/TN/FP/FN values. Instead, i have the given probabilities for "Good" or "Poor" classification, likeso:

```
    GoodPoor=c("Good","Good","Poor","Poor","Good","Good","Poor","Poor","Good","Poor")
    prob1=c(0.73, 0.69, 0.44, 0.55, 0.67, 0.47, 0.08, 0.15, 0.45, 0.35)
```

so I create the roc() object giving my desired threshold

```
    M1=as.list(cbind(GoodPoor, prob1))
    roc1_t5<-roc(GoodPoor ~ prob1, M1, thresholds = 0.5)
```

Now, I know that pROC package provides the specificity and sensitivity via roc1_t5$sensitivities and roc1_t5$specificities , but it doesn't seem to provide the precision. My question is: Is there a way to get the precision WITHOUT using other 'roc' packages? Thanks for your time

Comment: By precision i mean precision. precision=TP/(TP+FP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `coords` function will return the precision (among other values if you want them) of an ROC curve, as long as you also provide a threshold value.

Example:

```
> coords(roc1_t5, 0.5, ret=c("threshold", "precision", "recall"))
threshold precision    recall 
0.5000000 0.6666667 0.8000000
```

Example along with the use of `sapply`, so you can see the values as you change threshold:

```
> sapply(seq(0, 1, by=0.05), function(x) coords(roc1_t5, x, ret=c("precision", "recall")))
          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]     [,11]     [,12]
precision  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0   0.8 0.6666667 0.7142857
recall       0    0  0.2  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.6  0.6   0.8 0.8000000 1.0000000
              [,13]     [,14]     [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21]
precision 0.7142857 0.7142857 0.5555556   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
recall    1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
```

Also check the `"all"` value place of a specific threshold:

```
> coords(roc1_t5, "all", ret = c("threshold", "recall", "precision"))
      all       all   all       all       all  all   all   all  all   all  

all
threshold Inf 0.7100000 0.680 0.6100000 0.5100000 0.46 0.445 0.395 0.25 0.115 -Inf
recall    1.0 1.0000000 1.000 1.0000000 0.8000000 0.80 0.800 0.600 0.40 0.200    0
precision 0.5 0.5555556 0.625 0.7142857 0.6666667 0.80 1.000 1.000 1.00 1.000  NaN
```

And lastly another option for you is to plot the precision and recall together:

```
plot(precision ~ recall, t(coords(roc1_t5, "all", ret = c("recall", "precision"))), type="l")
```

Look at more possibilities for the `ret` argument in the documentation:

```
?coords
```